# R Shiny pages on IE10

Tags: r, internet-explorer-10, shiny

I have a windows machine. I use R shiny (R 3.0.1 and Shiny 0.10.2.1) to share some apps with others on the same network.

Just running an app using runApp("some_app") works fine on chrome/IE10 but not of much use because others on the network can't access it. When I run using: runApp("some_app", host="XX.XXX.XX.XXX", port=3456), others can access the page but can't see any reactive output only on IE10.

Any idea what would be the problem with reactive output on IE10 when I use my computer's ip while it works okay on chrome?

Many Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post additional information in comments - edit your original post instead (using the nice & friendly "edit" button :-) )

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert, but my impression is that a lot of things don't work in IE, especially things that are new / cool.

A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=shiny%20in%20internet%20explorer&oq=shiny%20in%20internet%20explorer&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.4215j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) provided some helpful links, especially [this one on shiny's google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/tqeURyiPmFI).

If people really can't use Chrome or Firefox, I would consider having people connect to a remote server that does have Chrome installed.